# Special characters in filename resulted in "remote: GitLab: API is not accessible"

Tags: git, gitlab, git-push

I was working on my project using git. I'm using some remote git repos for it. After some successful push commands, one of the remotes returned bellow errors for my new push command:

```
remote: GitLab: API is not accessible
To https://git.fosscommunity.in/mehdi/mikfrm.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 
'https://git.fosscommunity.in/mehdi/mikfrm.git'
```

I need to say that all previous commits and pushes on all remotes were done exactly the same, and it's strange that JUST this remote returned these errors! (all remotes are some public GitLab servers)

I did some google and find out it's maybe because of the special-character issue in some filenames. Referring to my local project folder I found a file with the name "####################" (the file was created unintentionally at the project folder). I deleted the file from the local copy and tried to commit and push again, but unfortunately, the same error still remained! (and again JUST for this Gitserver and not other servers).
I tried to login the web panel of my project on the Git server and delete that file from the web panel, but unfortunately, the same "API is not accessible" error was returned there too!

[Web error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjPEd.png)

Whould you please someone help me to resolve the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved. Many thanks to fosscommunity Gitlab maintainers, "Pirate Bady" and "Pirate ‍Praveen. I reported the issue to them and they fixed the issue.
As they told, the issue was related to the Ruby version of the Gitlab server.

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=964097